# Access denied while scraping a website with selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, access-denied, data-extraction

Hi I'm trying to extract information from Macy's website, specifically from this category = 'https://www.macys.com/shop/featured/women-handbags'. But when I access a particular item page I get a blank page with the following message:

Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "any of the items links listed on the above category link" on this server.
Reference #18.14d6f7bd.1526927300.12232a22

I've also tried changing the user agent with chrome options but it didn't work.

This is my code:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = 'https://www.macys.com/shop/featured/women-handbags'

def init_selenium():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/rodrigopeniche/Downloads/chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)

def find_page_items():
    items_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.productThumbnailItem')
    for index, element in enumerate(items_elements):
    items_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.productThumbnailItem')
    item_link = items_elements[index].find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
    driver.get(item_link)
    driver.back()


init_selenium()
find_page_items()
```

Any idea what's going on and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ as in _access a particular item page_?

Comment: @SIM Yeah that could be confusing, I just wrote an aclaration in the question. The links are accessible when trying to get them in a real browser but not when running the script.

Comment: Well, what do you wanna parse from there? There may be an alternative solution based on your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a selenium oriented solution (all through) but it works. You can give it a try.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.macys.com/shop/featured/women-handbags'

def find_page_items(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    item_link = [item.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href') for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.productThumbnailItem')]
    for newlink in item_link:
        res = requests.get(newlink,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        name = soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name']").text.strip()
        print(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        find_page_items(driver,url)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Mercer Medium Bonded-Leather Crossbody
Mercer Large Tote
Nolita Medium Satchel
Voyager Medium Multifunction Top-Zip Tote
Mercer Medium Crossbody
Kelsey Large Crossbody
Medium Mercer Gallery
Mercer Large Center Tote
Signature Raven Large Tote
```

However, If you stick to selenium then you need to create new instance of it everytime you browse a new url or may be a better option is to clear the cache.